# asp.net mvc display image without using database

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to display the images and nodes that I uploaded to the server in next page.

Here my code:
'

```
public ActionResult Review(HttpPostedFileBase uploadfile)
        {

            string note = Request.Form["note"];
            string deliverytime = Request.Form["time"];
            HttpPostedFileBase imagetest = Request.Files["uploadfile"];
            System.Drawing.Bitmap bmpPostedImage = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(imagetest.InputStream);
            string imagestring = imagetest.ContentType.ToString();
            ViewBag.Mime = "image/jpeg";
Stream stream = uploadfile.InputStream;
                byte[] image = new byte[uploadfile.ContentLength];
                stream.Read(image, 0, uploadfile.ContentLength);
 ViewBag.Message = Convert.ToBase64String(image, Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks);
                 ViewData["note"] = "user note:"+note;
               return PartialView();
}
```

'
and cshtml

```
@Html.Encode(ViewData["note"])<br />
<img src="data:@ViewBag.Mime;base64,@ViewBag.Message" />
```

The image can not display in next page. Thanks a lot for your help!